Set up GeForce GT 620 for Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 in my PC, but it seems that it does not work that well with my video card (GeForce GT 620). It only works with the nouveau drivers, which have abysmal performance, especially for youtube. If I try to install the nvidia dirivers with sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460 for example, the system won't boot.
So, is there any way to have good performance for my video card, or should I buy another one?

If you want to use Nvidia drivers you must purchase a newer card.

OK, but what that card could be? Was there an announcement from nvidia that they do not support old cards? Which one I should upgrade to?

I don't know; I'm in a similar situation with a GT 730. I used to be able to run Nvidia 340 drivers on it as long as I ran 20.04 with the original kernel, but even that stopped working in a recent update. So nouveau it is. That particular computer could accept a GTX 1050 (for example) which is supported, but since I only use it for running one old application, it's not worth it to me.

The last driver for your card is the 390 series, which does not work on the 6.8 kernel series. As @OrganicMarble said, it's time for a new card.

@ajgringo619 thanks for the info. Seems that I should buy a new one, but that's just shity,

Well, you could stay on Ubuntu 20.04 if you're not inclined to replace the card.

@ajgringo619 that's not the point. I do not understand why support for an old card should be dropped for a new kernel

There is no need for you to buy a newer graphics card. Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) extends Ubuntu's support lifetime from 5 years to 10 years for LTS versions of Ubuntu 14.04 and later. ESM is offered by Ubuntu Pro for free for personal use on up to 5 machines (limitations apply). All you need is an Ubuntu One account.

From the standpoint of extending the usable lifetime of your GeForce GT 620 graphics card you get an extended 5 years of support (until 2032) which at least saves the money it would cost to buy another graphics card which you don't need. My suggestion is to try to install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver on Ubuntu 22.04. At some point you might consider putting this package on hold to prevent it from being updated. That way a software update won't be able to ruin your current proprietary Nvidia graphics driver installation.
To install the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers that are compatible with your GeForce GT 620 you might also need to enable the repositories for older releases that are not supported by following the instructions in How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?.

Pro is free for up to 5 machines. I use all 5

OK I agree that I could stay with 22.04, I could do that without Ubuntu Pro for 2 more years, but the question here is if I can make the card work efficiently for 24.04, which is not the case

My problem is it that I want it to work with 24.04. I was already using 22.04 with no problem, so I'm not downgrading to 20.04

Thanks for commenting. I was not aware that it still works in 22.04. It seems like you want to install the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver from 22.04 in 24.04. That's going to give you some unmet dependencies and broken packages issues. You can ask some AI chatbot to give you examples of what these possible package management issues are. That's a safe question to ask an AI chatbot as long as you don't do anything about it.

Such old cards require the old proprietary unsupported 390 drivers. Seems like somebody adapted it to 24.04 in a papa: https://launchpad.net/~dtl131/+archive/ubuntu/nvidiaexp.  I haven't tested it myself but had to use such ppa for 22.04 and a 560gtx card if I remember correctly.
